Trying to create a array of IPs from an API call - POWERSHELL
$IPs ($IPs.Start and $IPs.End) gives me:



Start
End




12.1.15.100



7.10.9.200



3.3.40.100
3.3.40.135


100.20.3.8
100.20.4.255



I want to create an array of all the start IPs and the end IPs. The ones that have a Start and End are ranges of IP addresses. Maybe RegEx would be the best way to express that?
My array should look like:
$NewIPs = @(
   '12.1.15.100',
   '7.10.9.200',
   '3.3.40.100 - 3.3.40.135', # HOWEVER TO EXPRESS THIS SO THE ARRAY IS ALL IPs IN THIS RANGE
   '100.20.3.8 - 100.20.4.255'
)
   

EDIT: My question is how can I build this? I really don't know how to get a start on this besides building a list of each category (start + end) and combining them together without the range of IPs I'm looking for.

What's your question? What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

You may visit by this help topic: How much research effort is expected

Your question is unclear as @Olaf stated. Is $NewIPs the end goal or are you actually looking to create an IP Range from $ip.Start till $ip.End for each $ip in $IPs ?

@SantiagoSquarzon Create an IP Range. $NewIPs is a little misleading but that is pretty much the end goal.

Why would you attempt to generate all the values in the range? Sounds like a waste of memory :) If you're simply trying to answer the question "does IP address X.X.X.X fall within a given range?" then there are much simpler and more efficient ways


An easy way to create IP ranges is with the IPAddressRange library. The package can be downloaded from Nuget:
Invoke-WebRequest https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/IPAddressRange -OutFile IPAddressRange.zip
Expand-Archive .\IPAddressRange.zip

Creating IP ranges with it is quite simple:
if ($IsCoreCLR) {
    Add-Type -Path .\IPAddressRange\lib\net7.0\IPAddressRange.dll
}
else {
    Add-Type -Path .\IPAddressRange\lib\net462\IPAddressRange.dll
}

[NetTools.IPAddressRange]::new('100.20.3.8 - 100.20.4.255').IPAddressToString

# 100.20.3.8
# 100.20.3.9
# 100.20.3.10
# ...
# ...
# 100.20.4.255

Applied to your code:
$NewIPs = $IPs | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.End) {
        $range = [NetTools.IPAddressRange]::new(
            [ipaddress] $_.Start,
            [ipaddress] $_.End)

        return $range.IPAddressToString
    }

    $_.Start
}


Fantastic. Any way to not get PS to output the IP range in quotes? new('100.20.3.8 - 100.20.4.255')

@greenGob19 i don't understand what you mean. maybe assign to a variable? $var = ....new('100.20.3...')

That did work. Thanks! ALSO, I get a 'failed to create file' with the Expand-Archive command, even after deleting it and running the script again. It spams it in the terminal. Any input on that?

$NewIPs = 
    foreach ( $IP in $IPs ) {
        if ($IP.End) {
            [int]$from = $IP.Start.Split('.')[-1]
            [int]$till = $IP.End.Split('.')[-1]
            $base = $IP.Start -replace "\d*$", ''
            $range = $from..$till | foreach { $base + $_ }
            $range -join ' - '
        }
        else {
             $IP.Start
        }
    }


please let us know how this code is dealing with OP's last example range!

@SantiagoSquarzon what you mean 'OP's last example range'
