How to separate dashes in IP ranges to build range
I have a list of IP addresses as follows (pulled from API):
$IPs = @(
1.1.1.1-1.1.1.9,
5.5.5.1-5.5.5.3,
8.2.2.2-8.2.2.3
)

How can I separate these ranges so I can use a function I already have built to build a list of all these IPs.
For instance, the separation I want would be something like $IP.start and $IP.end to look like this when $IP is called



start
end




1.1.1.1
1.1.1.9


5.5.5.1
5.5.5.3


8.2.2.2
8.2.2.3



EDIT: What I am trying to get done here is a separated list of these ranges that I can dot-walk through the start and end of each range. I already have a function to build the range. Thanks!

Isnt this a duplicate of? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78699062/trying-to-create-a-array-of-ips-from-an-api-call-powershell

@SantiagoSquarzon I edited it.

@yy edited. thanks

$IPsObjects =
    foreach ($IP IN $IPs) {

        $Start,$end = $IP -split '-'

        [PSCustomObject]@{ Start = $start ; End = $end }

    }

Output
Start   End
-----   ---
1.1.1.1 1.1.1.9
5.5.5.1 5.5.5.3
8.2.2.2 8.2.2.3


Somebody copied my code.  my answer was earlier, but I got negative points.

@jdweng I posted my (similar and shorter) answer before I saw yours, you can see its posted on about the same minute.

Perhaps you're after the display of the Start and End of the range while still being able to reference the ranges of them?
Update-TypeData -TypeName CustomRange -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName ToString -Value { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Start = $this.Start
        End   = $this.End
    }   
} -Force -DefaultDisplayPropertySet Start, End

$ip_objects = @(
'1.1.1.1-1.1.1.9',
'5.5.5.1-5.5.5.3',
'8.2.2.2-8.2.2.3'
) | % { 
    (($start, $end = $_ -split '-') -replace '.+(?=\d$)') -join '..' | % {
        $octets = $start -replace '\d$'
        $ip_ranges = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Start = $start
            End   = $end
            Range = $(
                Invoke-expression -Command $_ -PipelineVariable range | % {
                    $octets + $range
                }
            )
        }
        $ip_ranges.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'CustomRange')
        $ip_ranges 
    }
}
$ip_objects

Without overcomplicating my explanation, we can use Update-TypeData to change the default display of a certain object type, which we customize our [PSCustomObject] to reflect just that with the help of .PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'CustomRange'). This allows us to only display Start and End while concealing Range to later on reference with $ip_objects[0].Range[2] outputting 1.1.1.3
Making use of Invoke-Expression by passing it the last octet of the Start and End IP joined with the range operator .., it will treat it as such and output the range from the start to end which we simply join back with $octets since it's just the first 3 octets allowing the full IP to be once more!

It’s worth noting the range only works here for addresses within the same /24 space - if you use something like 1.1.1.1-1.1.2.9 it ignores the 2 and just expands to the range of addresses in 1.1.1.1-1.1.1.9, which is fine for the OPs sample data, but won’t give a complete list for arbitrary ranges…

Try following :
$IPs = @(
'1.1.1.1-1.1.1.9',
'5.5.5.1-5.5.5.3',
'8.2.2.2-8.2.2.3'
)
$array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$IPArray = $IPs | foreach { $split = $_.Split('-'); ($array.Add($split[0]) | out-null); ($array.Add($split[1]) | out-null);  }
$array

Or this
$IPs = @(
'1.1.1.1-1.1.1.9',
'5.5.5.1-5.5.5.3',
'8.2.2.2-8.2.2.3'
)
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($IP in $IPs)
{
    $split = $IP.split('-')
    $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
       Start = $split[0]
       End = $split[1]
    }
    $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table

Results
Start   End
-----   ---
1.1.1.1 1.1.1.9
5.5.5.1 5.5.5.3
8.2.2.2 8.2.2.3


Why suggesting the deprecated ArrayList? if the collection is going to be read-only, a regular array is fine. Otherwise List[object] is better on every level.

It is not read only.  In the for loop each row is being added.  Where is ArrayList being deprecated?  Is there a replacement?

I meant read-only AFTER it was completely populated. For ArrayList being deprecated, it's technically Not Recommended  since... Net 2? Here an stack from 14 years ago about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309694/arraylist-vs-list-in-c-sharp
For replacement: Lists. Pretty much the same exact syntax except it doesn't returns the index on .Add() and it's more efficient both when dealing with heterogeneous lists and even more when dealing with homogeneous lists. It's basically better than ArrayList at everything.

This is Powershell not c#.  Both use Net Library.  I found the ArrayList in powershell documentation.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.4#arraylist.

Powershell uses .NET classes and libraries. Also: please read the last paragraph in the section you linked: "The ArrayList is deprecated in support for the generic List[]".

This does not work.  Cannot find 'List' : $list = [List[PSObject]]::new()  Should be $table = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()

I mean.. yeah? I didn't use the full name for short, but how to call it is in the docs you linked.

@sirtao : just replace $table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new() with  $table = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]::new()
